# how to change mime_type in Erlang?

Tags: erlang, mime-types

```
httpd:info(Pid).
      [{mime_types,[{"html","text/html"},{"htm","text/html"}]},
      {server_name,"httpd_test"},
      {bind_address, {127,0,0,1}},
      {server_root,"/tmp"},
      {port,59408},
      {document_root,"/tmp/htdocs"}]
```

I saw mime_type {"html", "text/html"} when I confirmed httpd information. but I wanna  these type add application/x-www-form-urlencoded
application/json
application/erlang-binary

but I can't find method.

Here is API doc.
    Administrative properties

```
{mime_types, [{MimeType, Extension}] | path()}
Where MimeType = string() and Extension = string(). Files delivered to the client are MIME typed according to RFC 1590. File suffixes are mapped to MIME types before file delivery. The mapping between file suffixes and MIME types can be specified as an Apache like file as well as directly in the property list. Such a file may look like:

# MIME type Extension  
text/html   html htm
text/plain  asc txt

Defaults to [{"html","text/html"},{"htm","text/html"}]

{mime_type, string()}
When the server is asked to provide a document type which cannot be determined by the MIME Type Settings, the server will use this default type.
```

How can i solve problem?

Comment: I can add mime_type but I can't add mime_types. what is the different

Comment: How do you attempt to add `mime_types`?  What error message do you get?

Comment: Thanks, your interesting. actually, I didn't add mime_types because I didn't know how to do. now that I solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-module(hello_world).
-export([start/0,service/3]).

start() ->
inets:start(httpd, [
{modules, [
mod_alias, 
mod_auth, 
mod_esi, 
mod_actions, 
mod_cgi, 
mod_dir, 
mod_get, 
mod_head, 
mod_log, 
mod_disk_log
]},
{port,8081},
{server_name,"hello_world"},
{server_root,"log"},
{document_root,"www"},
{erl_script_alias, {"/erl", [hello_world]}},
{error_log, "error.log"},
{security_log, "security.log"},
{transfer_log, "transfer.log"},
{mime_types,[
{"html","text/html"},
{"css","text/css"},
{"js","application/x-javascript"},
{"json","application/json"}
]}
]).

service(SessionID, Env, Input) ->
io:write(Env),
io:write(Input),
mod_esi:deliver(SessionID, [
"Content-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n", 
"<html><body>",
"Hello, World!</body></html>"
]).
```

this is sample code